# FreeIPA request certificate with cname

Tags: ssl, certificate, cname, a-records, freeipa

I while ago I was wondering how I could create an ssl-certificate for a cname. This came up as we always use generic a-records for our virtual machines. Services running on those virtual machines should be accessed by users by their service name over SSL. We use FreeIPA as our Certificate Authority.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you search for an answer for ages, and find the answer on multiple websites which are not very clear. I will explain my answer by means of an example to show the differences in requesting a certificate from FreeIPA **with** a cname and **without** a cname.

We make an imaginary virtual machine with an a-record being abc955-xy.example.com. On this machine we will run postgres. So, out of convenience, the cname will be postgresql.example.com. First we create a certificate for abc955-xy.example.com, which is only valid for the fqdn. Second, we create a certificate for the cname, which is also valid for the fqdn.

**Certificate without a cname**

```
# Generate a private key
openssl genrsa -out abc955-xy.example.com.key 4096

# Add the host to FreeIPA
ipa host-add abc955-xy.example.com --force

# Create a host principal for the service HTTP
ipa service-add HTTP/abc955-xy.example.com

# Add the host principal to the host
ipa service-add-host HTTP/abc955-xy.example.com --host abc955-xy.example.com

# Request a certificate for the host, using the principal and private key
ipa-getcert request -r -f abc955-xy.example.com.crt -k abc955-xy.example.com.key \ 
-K HTTP/abc955-xy.example.com -D abc955-xy.example.com
```

**Cerfificate including a cname**

```
# Generate a private key
openssl genrsa -out postgresql.example.com.key 4096

# Add the host to FreeIPA, using the cname
ipa host-add postgresql.example.com --force

# Create a host principal for the service HTTP
ipa service-add HTTP/abc955-xy.example.com

# Create a principal for the service HTTP with the cname
ipa service-add HTTP/postgresql.example.com --force

# Add the cname principal to the host
ipa service-add-host HTTP/postgresql.example.com --host abc955-xy.example.com

# Request a certificate for the host, using the principal and private key and cname
ipa-getcert request -r -f postgresql.example.com.crt -k postgresql.example.com.key\
-K HTTP/postgresql.example.com -D postgresql.example.com -D abc955-xy.example.com
```

Other than some naming differences, the main difference between both options is that you add the HTTP-principal with the cname to the host instead of the HTTP-principal with the fqdn.

Note: since browsers such as Chrome and Chromium only accept certificates with a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) as of version 65, you need to add a Subject Alternative Name to certificates without a cname too. This is where the option -D comes from in the ipa-getcert request. For certificates without a cname, you have to supply the fqdn.

Comment: What's the purpose of the openssl genrsa... part? In other tutorials I've come across this hasn't been present (or needed). Perhaps it's because the host is already enrolled in IPA?

Comment: It could also be due to the fact that the key is stored in an NSS database, which stores the actual key. Then the request would look like: ipa-getcert request -d /path/to/database

Answer (score -1):

```
# Set variables
DOMAIN=domain.name
CNAME=cname
DEST_MACHINE=dest-machine

# Add CNAME DNS-record
# $CNAME => $DEST_MACHINE
ipa dnsrecord-add $DOMAIN $CNAME --cname-hostname=$DEST_MACHINE

# Generate a private key
## to /etc/pki/tls/private
## or another dir (*selinux fcontext* of that dir should be *cert_t*)
sudo openssl genrsa -out /etc/pki/tls/private/$CNAME\_$DEST_MACHINE.key 4096

# Create HTTP service for $DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN
ipa service-add HTTP/$DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN

# Add alias HTTP/$CNAME\.$DOMAIN for HTTP/$DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN
ipa service-add-principal HTTP/$DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN HTTP/$CNAME\.$DOMAIN

# Request a certificate for HTTP/$DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN
# for a DNSNAMEs:
## $DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN
## $CNAME\.$DOMAIN
sudo ipa-getcert request -r \
-f /etc/pki/tls/private/$CNAME\_$DEST_MACHINE.crt \
-k /etc/pki/tls/private/$CNAME\_$DEST_MACHINE.key \
-K HTTP/$DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN \
-D $DEST_MACHINE\.$DOMAIN \
-D $CNAME\.$DOMAIN

# Show info about certificate requests
sudo ipa-getcert list

# List content of certificates dir
ls /etc/pki/tls/private/

# Now just use that certificates with your web-services
```